# How to wrap multiple paragraphs in one element?

Tags: java, itext, wrapper, paragraph

I'm creating a fairly complex PDF document in Java using iText 5. I add a bunch of `Paragraph` objects to my document. To improve readability of my code, I would like to create multiple methods to create different aspects of the document.

What type can I use to wrap multiple `Paragraph` objects in one unit, so I can return them from my sub-methods? The `Element` class does not have an `add()` method, nor does the `Chunk` class.

I tried `Phrase`, but then I lose all line breaks. Wrapping my `Paragraph` objects in another `Paragraph` object produces the desired output, but it feels odd, and I fear that the wrapping paragraph might introduce additional margins in the document.

So what is the best type for wrapping `Paragraph` objects in order to group them logically?

---

### Code example

My current code:

```
Document doc = new Document(...);
doc.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.1"));
doc.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.2"));
doc.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.3"));

doc.add(new Paragraph("Aspect B.1"));
doc.add(new Paragraph("Aspect B.2"));
```

What I'm striving for:

```
Document doc = new Document(...);
doc.add(createAspectA());
doc.add(createAspectB());

// ...

private WrapperElement createAspectA() {
  WrapperElement wrapper = new WrapperElement(...);

  wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.1"));
  wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.2"));
  wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.3"));

  return wrapper;
}

private WrapperElement createAspectB() {
  WrapperElement wrapper = new WrapperElement(...);

  wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect B.1"));
  wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect B.2"));

  return wrapper;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wrapping my `Paragraph` objects in another `Paragraph` object produces the desired output, but it feels odd

While this indeed may feel odd, it does work and is a use case explicitly considered in the code. (For example look at the code of `Paragraph.breakUp()` and the inherited `Phrase.process(ElementListener).`)

> and I fear that the wrapping paragraph might introduce additional margins in the document

It only does if you ask it to (using `setIndentationLeft(float)` / `setIndentationRight(float)` / `setSpacingAfter(float)` / `setSpacingBefore(float)`). Thus, you have the *option* to add extra indentation but you are not *unwillingly subject* to unwanted extra indentation.

---

On the other hand, if you want to be 100% sure that there cannot be any unwanted influence, you can simply return an ordered `Iterable<Element>`, e.g. an `ArrayList<Element>`, and change the adding to the document to a `forEach` call:

```
private Iterable<Element> createAspectA() {
    ArrayList<Element> wrapper = new ArrayList<>();

    wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.1"));
    wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.2"));
    wrapper.add(new Paragraph("Aspect A.3"));

    return wrapper;
}
```

and replace

```
doc.add(createAspectA());
```

by

```
for (Element e : createAspectA())  doc.add(e);
```

(Unfortunately `doc.add` throws tagged exceptions, otherwise it could have been `createAspectA().forEach(doc::add)`.)